# How to add id to url for Http get request with Angular

Tags: angular, http

I have a function in an angular2 service, which is passed an id to append to a base URL for a Http get request however it doesn't work. When i put in the exact string it gets the data fine, but it won't let me append the variable like

'http://localhost:3000/project/allTask/' + project_id

```
getTasks(project_id){
  this.loadToken();
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/project/allTask/5b0919ea256f2e15f8f4364f' , {headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Update:

I believe the project_id when passed in undefined. This is a function of my component.

```
ngOnInit() {

this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
   this.user_id = profile.user._id;
   console.log(this.user_id); //RETURNS CORRECT ID HERE
},
err =>{
   console.log(err);
   return false;
});

console.log(this.user_id);//UNDEFINED

this.authService.getProjects(this.user_id).subscribe(data => {
   this.projects = data;
},
err =>{
   console.log(err);
   return false;
});
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `project_id` contains the correct string? Try to log it to the console to check.

Comment: Listen to @Henry, make a console log of your ID, because from what you say you tried, it should work.

Comment: It is undefined when it enters this function which is odd.

Comment: The log in the first lambda expression is executed after the second one. The user_id is only set after you receive an answer from the getProfile call. Read about asynchronous execution.

Comment: Thanks for your help Henry. Anyway to fix it in the mean time though?

Comment: You could move the code starting at the second log statement into the first lambda expression (immediately after the first log statement).

Comment: Thank you so much this worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use it like this:

```
getTasks(project_id){
  this.loadToken();
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/project/allTask/' + project_id, {headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

or

```
getTasks(project_id){
  this.loadToken();
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
  return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/project/allTask/${project_id}`, {headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: You're not using the correct operator for string templates.

Comment: @trichetriche is it fine now?

Comment: (But in your first example, it's trivial, you shouldn't have edited the first chunk of code. But since it works, that's just being picky)